# Gradle task should not execute automatically

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm defining a task in gradle:

```
task releaseCandidate(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'git', 'checkout', 'develop'

    // Increment version code in Manifest
    String manifest = new File('AndroidManifest.xml').getText('UTF-8')
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('android:versionCode="([0-9]+)"')
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(manifest)
    matcher.find()
    int newVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1
    manifest = manifest.replaceAll(
        "android:versionCode=\"([0-9]+)\"", "android:versionCode=\"$newVersionCode\""
    )
    new File('AndroidManifest.xml').write(manifest, 'UTF-8')

    commandLine 'git', 'diff'
}
```

Which I want to execute only when I explicitly call it as `gradle releaseCandidate`. **However, when I run any other task, such as `gradle assembleDebug`, it also runs task releaseCandidate.** I don't want that behaviour to happen. There is no task depending on releaseCandidate or vice-versa.

My project is an Android app, so I am using `android` gradle plugin.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A common pitfall. Add an action to the task otherwise code will run at configuration phase. Sample task with action:

```
task sample << {
}
```

As I see You'd rather need to write a custom task than using `Exec` type. I suppose it's not valid to define `commandLine` twice.

**EDIT**

You can read [this](https://blog.softwaremill.com/my-task-whats-wrong-with-your-gradle-task-82312100c595) post to get the general idea how it all works.

Comment: Precisely. I was aware of the `<<` shortcut, but the docs didn't make that behaviour on configuration phase clear.

Comment: Well, ok. Do You know how to configure it right now? If not feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 19):

You are mixing Task configuration and groovy code. Everything that is part of the main body of a task definition will be executed in the configuration phase. The `task task1 << { code }` is a shorthand for

```
task task1 {
  doLast {
    code
  }
}
```

`commandLine` is part of the [Exec Task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) but your other code is not and should be wrapped into a `doLast` this will execute the commandline first and then execute your additional code. If you need another exec `commandLine` then you'll need another task.

```
task releaseCandidate(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'git', 'checkout', 'develop'

    doLast {
    // Increment version code in Manifest
    String manifest = new File('AndroidManifest.xml').getText('UTF-8')
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('android:versionCode="([0-9]+)"')
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(manifest)
    matcher.find()
    int newVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + 1
    manifest = manifest.replaceAll(
        "android:versionCode=\"([0-9]+)\"", "android:versionCode=\"$newVersionCode\""
    )
    new File('AndroidManifest.xml').write(manifest, 'UTF-8')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete @Opal answer for cases when **Exec** is really used (for example **CommandLine** reference) :

```
task task1 << {
   exec {
        List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>()
        //..
        commandLine arguments
   }
}
```