# How to run a single gradle task from command line

Tags: java, gradle

In my project I have several tasks in my build.gradle. I want those tasks to be independent while running. ie I need to run a single task from command line. But the command "gradle taskA" will run both taskA and taskB which I do not want. How to prevent a task being running?.

Here's a sample of what I am doing.

```
   task runsSQL{
    description 'run sql queries'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    print 'Run SQL'  }

task runSchema{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    print 'Run Schema' }
```

Here's the output I'm getting.
[image]

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350

Comment: I see that you run `gradle` command. I can't find `gradle.exe` on my PC. I'm new to Android and Gradle build system. Where can I find the gradle executable?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Use `gradlew` if you don't have Gradle installed (most Gradle projects contain the wrapper `gradlew`), otherwise you can install Gradle from [the Gradle website](http://gradle.org).

Comment: You do not need to apply each plugin to each task individually. Simply doing `apply plugin: 'java'` and `apply plugin: 'groovy'` at the start of the file will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-x` option or `--exclude-task` switch to exclude task from task graph. But it's good idea to provide runnable example.

Comment: gradle taskA -x taskB will run both the tasks.

Comment: Ok, that's why I told  you to provide an example - now it's quite an abstract discussion.

Comment: Ok, but there's no `taskA` and `taskB` defined. It's difficult to reproduce the error now. Which tasks are You trying to run? Also You didn't add *actions* to tasks. Thus the code in closures is run during *configuration* time.

Comment: runSQL and runSchema are the tasks I have not taskA and taskB (I just picked that names for simplicity). I didn't add the actions because those are quite big. But I can say its about reading some sql queries from files and executing it based on some conditions. Also both tasks accept arguments from commandline.

Comment: Hmm.. The script you provided seems to be strange :/ Please provide a simple but runnable script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please see the updated code. While running the task runSQL I'm expecting the output "Run SQL" only.

Comment: Ok, the tasks isn't run - I mean action is not invoked. The message is printed because it's configuration phase - not execution. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 26):

I guess the point that you missed is that you dont define tasks here but you configured tasks. Have a look at the gradle documentation: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html.

What you wanted is something like this:

```
task runsSQL (dependsOn: 'runSchema'){
    description 'run sql queries'
    println 'Configuring SQL-Task' 
    doLast() {
        println "Executing SQL"
    }
}

task runSchema << {
    println 'Creating schema' 
}
```

Please mind the shortcut '<<' for 'doLast'. The doLast step is only executed when a task is executed while the configuration of a task will be executed when the gradle file is parsed.

When you call

```
gradle runSchema
```

You'll see the *'Configuring SQL-Task'* and afterwards the *'Creating schema'* output. That means the runSQLTask will be configured but not executed.

If you call

```
gradle runSQL
```

Than you you'll see:

Configuring SQL-Task
:runSchema
Creating schema
:runsSQL
Executing SQL

runSchema is executed because runSQL depends on it.

Comment: Yes. That answers the question.Thanks