# Task is always up to date

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've got a gradle build with a task like the following

```
task createFolders {
  file(rootFolder).mkDirs()
}
```

Note that in the real system there are about 15 folders getting created during this task.

This task always reports as UP-TO-DATE when I run the task, even if I run it directly after deleted the folders being created.  I have several tasks that depend on this task and they run.

How do I tell gradle that this task is only up to date if all the created folders exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because folders are created during **configuration** phase. Add an action:

```
task createFolders << {
  file(rootFolder).mkDirs()
}
```

For more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll accept the answer when I can.  Earlier I had an error that said I was misusing the '<<' and so I'd removed it.  I was having other issues and I guess getting rid of those allowed me to put that back.