# Gradle Copy Task is always Up To Date

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

My gradle task looks like this

```
task xml_file_to_vs_build(type: Copy) {
   outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
   doLast {
      outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
      println("copying strings.xml");
      from 'src/main/res/values'
      into '../vso_build'
      include 'strings.xml'
   }
}
```

The task is always up to date . If I put the block in the configuration phase i.e. out of doLast, everything works fine. But then the code executed even if I execute gradlew Tasks which I do not want. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it solved? Maybe i met the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198227/gradle-task-type-copy-and-dolast-cant-both-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the task in the following way:

```
task xml_file_to_vs_build(type: Copy) {
   println("copying strings.xml")
   from 'src/main/res/values'
   into '../vso_build'
   include 'strings.xml'
}
```

Comment: The println runs even when I do gradle Tasks but the copy does not. That is a bit confusing right ?

Comment: Please have a look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350. This `println` is executed at configuration time.

Comment: Yes I understand the concept of execution and configuration phase. So My question is how do I make the entire task only work in execution phase and not suffer from the UpToDate problems like above?

Comment: I should work well with the task definition above. Remove `strings.xml` from `../vso_build`. Run `gradle xml_file_to_vs_build` - file should be copied. Run `gradle xml_file_to_vs_build` again - task should be up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

A Copy task only gets executed if it has something to copy. Telling it what to copy is part of configuring the task, and therefore needs to be done in the configuration phase, rather than the execution phase. These are very important concepts to understand, and you can read up on them in the Gradle User Guide or on the Gradle Forums.

doFirst and doLast blocks get executed in the execution phase, as part of executing the task. Both are too late to tell the task what to copy: doFirst gets executed immediately before the main task action (which in this case is the copying), but (shortly) after the skipped and up-to-date checks (which are based on the task's configuration). doLast gets executed after the main task action, and is therefore clearly too late.