# Gradle Task . "(type: Copy)" and <doLast> can't both work

Tags: gradle, copy

```
task simpleTask{
    print("simpleTask is reach");
}

task copySomeFile(type: Copy){
    print("copySomeFile is reach");
    from baseProjectPath;
    into toProjectPath;
    appendXML();
}
def appendXML(){
    //modify a.txt
}
```

//i just want to run "simpleTask" only, but when "gradle simpleTask", the task"copySomeFile" will be run also ! I know beacuse gradle initialization.

but if write like this

```
task copySomeFile(type: Copy)<<{
}
```

the "copySomeFile" will not work.

it seems like "(type: Copy)" can't work with the "<<" or "doLast{}"?

i just want "--gradle simpleTask" "--gradle copySomeFile" can run alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read about [Gradle build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

There are 2 phases you should note - `Configuration` and `Execution`. All tasks are always been configured on every build, but only some of them are really executed as the Execution phase.

What you see is that `copySomeFile` task was configured during the configuration phase. It doesn't copy anything, but it has to be configured. And everything within a tasks closure is task's configuration, that is why you see results of the `print("copySomeFile is reach");` in the output.

`<<` or `doLast` are used to run something at the Execution phase, but your task of type Copy will not be configured if you place all it's configuration into `doLast` section or add `<<` to the task definition - that is the reason why copy doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot.@Stanislav 
You've made me learn a lot.
And if there's a way to make the code work?
`task copySomeFile(type: Copy)<<{
    print("copySomeFile is reach");
    from baseProjectPath;
    into toProjectPath;//how can i reach here?
}`
or it can't write like that.thanks again

Comment: and the "appendXML()" in "copySomeFile" executed when i used "gradle simpleTask".
I see the content of <a.txt> was change. It's so confusing.

Comment: @XaoFay https://gist.github.com/jnizet/d38ce94b846130dfae704bf3ad069e6e

Comment: as it's made in the example above, you can have a `doLast` closure in your configuration and call `appendXML()` from it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeh, i got it. How much I appreciate both of you. SHARE THE CODE:

```
task simpleTask {
    print("\nsimpleTask is configured"); // executed during the configuration plase, always
    doLast {
        print("\nsimpleTask is executed"); // executed during the execution plase, only if the simpleTask is executed
    }
}

task copySomeFile(type: Copy) {
    print("\ncopySomeFile is configured"); // executed always,执行其他任务时,此代码也会执行
    from "D:/a.txt";// not executed. 执行其他任务时,此代码不会执行
    into "D:/b.txt";// not executed. 执行其他任务时,此代码不会执行
    doLast {
        appendXML(); //only this task executed, the appendXML executed. 只有此task执行时,才会执行.比如(gradle copySomeFile);
    }
}
def appendXML(){
    print("\nappendXML");
}
```