# Gradle protobuf custom task

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers

Given this protobuf gradle configuration:

[image: protobuf configuration]

When we execute `generateProto` task (which is generated by protobuf plugin) we will get following output:

[image: output]

As you can see the custom defined task `cleanProto` is getting executed before `generateProto`.

**Why is it executing at all if I havent defined dependency between those tasks?**

Comment: which protobuf plugin are you using?

Comment: com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.0 but it seems i was defining wrong task, when i changed task definition to "task(cleanProto) << {" it worked as expected, but i dont understand why, whats the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually.. it's not executed at all. The `println` statement is executed at *configuration* phase, not at *execution* phase. To verify it, change `cleanProto` to:

```
task cleanProto << {
   println 'deleting gen'
   delete 'gen'
}
```

Now, it won't execute at all if no dependency is defined. With `<<` an action is added. Actions are run during *execution* phase.

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350) answer as well.

P.S. Next time instead of providing images of the code, copy and paste it. You can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> combination - on Mac.

Comment: oh sure, i was accepting it right away but it had 5 mnute limitation then i forgot :D