# Gradle Task is there any difference using "<<" or not?

Tags: gradle

Is there any difference when creating a gradle task using the `<<`? 
I see some tasks created with it and without, for example:

```
task task1 << {}

task task2 {}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, big difference.

The latter executes the body in the configuration phase, the former in the execution phase.  Read the user guide PDF in the distribution to learn what those mean.