# when does doFirst is executed in gradle

Tags: gradle

Why 0000 does NOT exit after `gradle foo`? After I remove `doFirst` `foo.doFirst{ delete '0000' }`, the 0000 is there.

`doFirst` should be executed before foo task scripts.

The docs says:

```
Task doFirst(Closure action)

Adds the given closure to the beginning of this task's action list. The closure is passed this task as a parameter when executed.
```

Full command log:

```
isaac-mbp:swap isaac$ cat build.gradle
task foo {
    mkdir '0000/a'
    mkdir '0000/b'
}
foo.doFirst{ delete '0000' }

isaac-mbp:swap isaac$ gradle foo
:foo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.581 secs
isaac-mbp:swap isaac$ ls -lha 0000
ls: cannot access 0000: No such file or directory
isaac-mbp:swap isaac$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.14
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-06-14 07:16:37 UTC
Revision:     cba5fea19f1e0c6a00cc904828a6ec4e11739abc

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_25 (Oracle Corporation 25.25-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

1. A task is (simplifying) a collection of actions that are executed in order they were added
2. `build.gradle` is run in two phases: *configuration* and *execution*.

The logic (`mkdir`s) in the following piece of code will be executed *every* time `build.gradle` is evaluated since it's added in *configuration* time:

```
task foo {
    mkdir '0000/a'
    mkdir '0000/b'
}
```

To fix it - add an action:

```
task foo << {
    mkdir '0000/a'
    mkdir '0000/b'
}
```

And now `doFirst`:

```
task foo << {
        mkdir '0000/a'
        mkdir '0000/b'
}
foo.doFirst { delete '0000' }
```

Now the task has 2 actions: `mkdirs`s and `delete` and they will be executed in an appropriate order. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350) as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! really saved me hours of time. going to learn more about gradle configuration phase.