# Run only one task from build.gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, teamcity

You can run only one task, from one file, with more tasks?

I have `build.gradle` file

```js
task RunA {
    println 'A'
}

task RunB{
    println 'B'
}

task RunC{
    println 'C'
}

task RunD{
    println 'D'
}
```

And I try run only one task `RunB` from IntelliJ or Teamcity. But result is

```
A
B
C
D
```

Why? Before, I used Ant.

I need this result after call RunB

```
B
```

**Really "intuitive" sulution**

```js
task RunA {
    doLast {
        println 'A'
    }
}

task RunB {
    doLast {
        println 'B'
    }
}

task RunC {
    doLast {
        println 'C'
    }
}

task RunD {
    doLast {
        println 'D'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564

Comment: I need RunB and other skip, not call from doLast

Comment: It seems that you need `doLast` actually none of the mentioned tasks run. You get the output from *configuration* phase. See here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350

Comment: Thanks for thoughts :)

Comment: If you found mentioned answers useful - please upvote them. That's how SO works.